# Нет доступа к таблице изнутри процедуры

Tags: mysql

Создаю процедуру внутри SQL запроса для последовательного вывода элементов JSON. Но почему то нет доступа к таблице при вызове её изнутри процедуры. Получаю ошибку "unknown column section_json in field list"

```
USE db;
DROP PROCEDURE my_while;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_while()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
   SET len = (SELECT section_json FROM app where app.number = "111030405");
    WHILE i < len DO
    SET s = CONCAT(s, "; ", TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(section_json, "$[i].role")), "; ",  CHAR(13));
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
SELECT s AS Выборка, i, len
from app 
where app.number = "111030405";
END $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL my_while ();
```

Comment: А у вас есть поле section_json в JSON?

Comment: Да, вне процедуры из него нормально выгружаются данные. Если просто SELECT section_json from app;

Comment: `SET len = (SELECT ..)` - так нельзя. Используйте SELECT INTO.

Comment: Error Code: 3954. Misplaced INTO clause, INTO is not allowed inside subqueries, and must be placed at end of UNION clauses.  

Код ошибки: 3954. Неуместное предложение INTO, INTO не допускается внутри подзапросов и должно быть помещено в конце предложений ОБЪЕДИНЕНИЯ.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_while()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE len INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
    WHILE i < (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(section_json ->> "$[*].role") INTO len FROM app) DO
    SET s = CONCAT(s, "; ", TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(section_json, "$[i].role")), "; ",  CHAR(13));
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
SELECT s AS Выборка, i, len
from application 
where app.number = "111";
END $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL my_while ();